# What is the exact regex pattern for negative numbers in the range -100.00 to 9999.99?

Tags: regex

I have to write a regular expression pattern in java for numbers in the range -100.00 to 9999.99  . The allowable number of decimal places is exactly 2. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info <-- read the tag wiki of the tag you used.

Comment: JavaScript <> Java

Comment: As the answers have been closed: I would use something like this:

`^((-[\d]{0,2}\.[\d]{2}|-100.00)|([\d]{0,4}\.[\d]{2}))`

This will match `-0.00` to `-100.00` and `0.00` to `9999.99`

For the example, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/mN6uT5/2)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking for the range from -100.00 to +9999.99. Hence the correct answer would be:

```
(?<!\d)(-\d\d?|-100|(?<!-)\d{1,4})\.\d{2}(?!\d)
```

Checking on both sides to validate that you aren't getting part of a number.

Answer (score 0):

`-\d{3,4}\.\d{2}`

**Explanation:**
`-` - match the minus
`\d{3,4}` - match three or four digits
`\.` - match fullstop
`\d{2}` -  match two digits

Comment: Please add some explainations to your regex

Comment: Thanks, yes, much better